# How to render a list of users from ReqRes API with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have been scouring over similar questions and can't find any that have been answered for this exact api. I know its really easy I'm just loosing my mind right now.. I just need a list of all the users from the reqres api.. if you have a look at the code below it explains what data I'm getting in the console logs. All I want to do is to render that as a list in the render method:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class User extends Component {
  state = {
    people: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
      .then(response => {
        this.successShow(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.successShow(error);
      });
  }

  successShow(response) {
    this.setState({
      people: response.data.data
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.people[0]);
    //this console log prints this:
    //{id: 1, first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"}

    console.log(this.state.people[1]);
    //this console log prints this:
    //{id: 2, first_name: "Janet", last_name: "Weaver", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"}

    return <div>HOW DO I RENDER A LIST OF ALL THE USERS HERE??</div>;
  }
}
export default User;
```

Comment: So what properties you want to `render()` out of `first_name` and `last_name` amd `avatar` and how to want to display them. Give html example of one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` on `this.state.people`

```
return (
  <ul>
    {this.state.people.map(({id, first_name, last_name, avatar}) => (
      <li key={id}>
        First Name: {first_name} Last Name: {last_name} avatar: {avatar}
      </li>))
    }
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: but don't use `index` as the key, use the `id` from the data to avoid issues with updates to the list. hmm.. thought that would suggest an edit, sorry..

Comment: Also this won't work until you wrap JS code with curly braces

Answer (score 2):

in your `render()` method just iterate through your people object, for example like that:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.state.people.map(person => (
        <li key={person.id}>{person.firstName}</li> 
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Just don't forget to use keys on iterated values

Comment: You forgot to add closing `}`